# Laravel Routing with a front-end Framework

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ember.js, reactjs

I have a laravel web app that I'm content with, but I want to use some javascript frameworks to do things like drag-and-drop. I've looked into Angular, Ember, and React but I haven't been able to find a straight answer to the routing concerns that I have:

- Can I continue to use Laravel's routing with these? Or mix and match?
- If I only set up one route on Angular for example, are all of the rest caught by Laravel? Or does it take over routing entirely?

I don't want to implement an entire javascript site with Laravel as an api, I'd like to use some of the out-of-the-box functionality that Laravel has, with javascript components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to run ember on a single page, even if most ember apps are the whole webpage. You can embed ember inline on a specific element say `#mywidget`:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#my-widget'
});
```

Then either turn off routing with `location: none` or specify the hash based routing:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'hash'
});
```

I've used ember both in the WordPress admin for my configuration and embedded inside of much larger pages. That said I wouldn't make a site where each page is it's own ember-app, that's really wasteful and misses the point of having a full frontend framework. Only if you have 1 page that has a particularly complex view.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should implement routes with Angular/Ember, because they are full-featured frontend frameworks. Frontend, made with one of these frameworks, should only talk to backend via ajax.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want a couple of pages to be handled by Laravel, but the rest by Angular/Ember - is that just outside of either's wheelhouse?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob It's perfectly fine to run ember on a single page. The router is just way of switching between states in your ember-app wholly separate from your webpage (even if most ember apps are the whole webpage). You can embed ember inline on an element say `#mywidget` and then either turn off routing or switch to the hash router.

Comment: Sure you can have some pages that will not be a part of Angular/Ember application, if you need.